# CM14.1 compile error

Tags: linux, android, compile

I'm trying to compile CM14.1 for my phone and as i'm close to the end of the process i get this error related to maven:

```
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(mvn -q org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:get                    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy       -DremoteRepositories=central::::https://maven.cyanogenmod.org/artifactory/gello_prebuilds       -Dartifact=org.cyanogenmod:gello:40:apk         -Dmdep.prependGroupId=true      -Dmdep.overWriteSnapshots=true      -Dmdep.overWriteReleases=true       -Dtransitive=false      -DoutputDirectory=/root/android/system/out/target/common/obj/APPS/Gello_intermediates/ )"
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:get (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Couldn't download artifact: Could not transfer artifact org.cyanogenmod:gello:apk:40 from/to central (https://maven.cyanogenmod.org/artifactory/gello_prebuilds): Connect to maven.cyanogenmod.org:443 [maven.cyanogenmod.org/216.168.38.166] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
[ERROR] org.cyanogenmod:gello:apk:40
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] central (https://maven.cyanogenmod.org/artifactory/gello_prebuilds, releases=true, snapshots=true)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:151: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/root/android/system'

#### make failed to build some targets (04:09 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by deleting by deleting ~/android/system/out folder and running `brunch shamu` once again